# Correct variants of sentence with "in about 10 minutes"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Are both of these sentences correct to say? (We will finish everything in about 10 min) :

- Мы закончим всё минут через десять.
- Мы закончим всё за десять минут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Мы закончим всё минут через десять.

The sentence is grammatical with emphasis on **when** everything will be done. *через* means *in approximately 10 minutes*

> 2.Мы закончим всё за десять минут.

This one has got another meaning due to the preposition *за*: It will take us ten minutes to do it.(How much time will it take?) Both are fine.

Comment: The meaning of "in **approximately** 10 minutes" comes not from "через" but from inversion. "Через десять минут" would mean "in ten minutes", that means "_exactly_ in ten minutes".

Comment: Ну...тогда уберите "через" и что у вас получится? вообще-то мы говорим не об "approximately ",а о предлогах. Я не понимаю, что Вы пытаетесь  править. Разве у меня нет инверсии?

Comment: Давайте уж тогда доведем до абсурда и уберем "закончим" и "минут". Что получится? При чем тут "уберем "через"? Я говорил о том, что значение приблизительности исходит не от слова "через", а от измененного порядка слов. "Через десять минут" и "минут через десять" имеют разный смысл, хотя слова одни и те же.

Comment: За не равно *через*.

Comment: Про _за_ я вообще ничего не говорил.

Comment: А про "через" вопросов нет и про инверсию тоже. И разногласий тоже.